# C# vs 2008 crystal reports exception on client machine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, x86, runtime-error

my client machine is 64 bit but the application i build is in x86 target platform in C# Visual studio 2008 with win7 32 bit. Now the problem is when i click crystal report button on my application it gives me this error. It works perfectly fine on development machine but on client i just see this message box again and again.

"An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal     Reports runtime is not installed correctly."

[image]

I have checked crystal reports even in prerequisites just like the attached picture [image]

Also i have installed manually crystal reports runtime from http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0.zip

But error seems not leaving my life at all.

I am using first time crystal reports in C# but it gave me very hard time just to install it on the client machine. I have googled and found solutions most of them i have tried like setting prerequisites and changing mode from Any CPU to x86 but none has fix my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer what i did is i have opend the directory in my development machine C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5 and copied the runtime exe for crystal reports and than i have ran it manually on the client machine. By doing this my client machine is now able to run crystal reports perfectly fine. I believe i should store this crystal report runtimes in my setup program for other clients.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC I've had a similar problem in the past caused by deploying Crystal with the Setup package. Have you tried uninstalling Crystal Runtime from the target machine and installing the correct (64-bit) runtime version onto it directly?

You can leave your target CPU as Any.

Comment: what i did now is i went to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5 and copied the runtime exe and ran it manually on the client machine...and guess what it worked but is this a correct way to do ???why i cannot set this through prerequisites

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work properly. I've found Crystal Reports for Visual Studio to be flaky in a few areas though.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is targeting x86 version and you are installing in 64 bit machine,right?
I think crpt x64 installer is corrupted.
After making installer,go to debug folder and find crystal report folder.You can see two crpt installer,one is x86 and another is x64. Delete x64 installer. copy x86 to another place and rename it as x64.Then recopy to crpt folder.Now check installation.
I think I can make you understand.